# How important is to include an acknowledgment in the poster presentation?

Tags: funding, acknowledgement, poster

The organization where I work provided me funding for a poster presentation. My opinion is to acknowledge the funding organization due to the research team of an organization is the authors of the paper.

> How important is to acknowledge the funding agency?

I am using Logo of organization in the poster.

> Using the Only logo will be good without acknowledgement in the
>   poster in Acknowledgement heading?

Comment: You work there, so naturally you use the logo. To acknowledge your employer for funding your work (and presenting a poster on your work is exactly that, *work*) seems a bit weird though. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is acceptable to use one or both ways unless there is a restriction policy from your organization or the committee of the event, at which the poster is going to be presented.

However, a poster is very short to present your work and ideas and you want to properly invest in the space. In my opinion, a logo is enough to acknowledge the funding agency. The assumption is that there are no other reasons to put a logo of any organization in your poster if it does not support the work in one way or another.